# How to catch browser activity?

Tags: android

I have an app which is launch browser by the next way:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(getURL());
    Context context = widget.getContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, context.getPackageName());
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

I have another AndroidJUnit project in which I want to catch that activity.

With next steps I can catch MYProjectActivity, which is runing browser, but I couldn't catch browser.

```
 Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation();

  // Register we are interested in the authentication activiry...
  Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor monitor = instrumentation.addMonitor(MYProjectActivity.class.getName(), null, false);

  // Start the authentication activity as the first activity...
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  intent.setClassName(instrumentation.getTargetContext(), MYProjectActivity.class.getName());
  instrumentation.startActivitySync(intent);

  // Wait for it to start...
  Activity currentActivity = getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor, 5);
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: I tried catching the browser start with an ActivityMonitor by passing an IntentFilter instead of a class to the addMonitor() method, and using Intent.ACTION_VIEW in the IntentFilter. It did not work in my code, but I think that is caused by some other problem, so maybe it works for you.

Comment: Jan, Thank you for your answer< but I should add that this activity monitor works only for startActivitySync method. In my application uses startActivity - for this method it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to monitor the browser as you are requesting, but offering an alternative thought:

You need to weigh out what your reasons are for using the Browser, but have you considered using a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) instead? It allows you much more control as you are able to place it into an Activity and observe intent traffic as well as Sub-Class WebView for more detailed callback info if you need it.